# Python Как получить текст между разделителями

Tags: python, list, numpy, текст, separator

Скажем у меня есть текст:

```
*Text_one # не должен вывестись

Separator:

Text_two # хочу получить 

Separator:

Text_three #хочу получить

Separator:*
```

Я хочу получить текст только между разделителями. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: вам по ТЗ нужно использовать numpy, или это не обязательно ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно по простому:

```
t = """Text_oneSeparatorText_twoSeparatorText_threeSeparator"""
tt = t.split("Separator")[1:-1] #вместо Separator вставить свой разделитель
print(tt)
```

Можно с помощью регулярных выражений:

```
import re
t = """Text_oneSeparatorText_twoSeparatorText_threeSeparator"""
rr = re.findall(r'(?s)(?<=Separator).*?(?=Separator)', t) #вместо Separator вставить свой разделитель
print(rr)
```